# Why are my views widening and then returning to normal during running of this code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

1. This is the code.
2. What more information do i need to put here?

I'm trying to find out why my text and button views are widening and then returning to normal during running of this code.

It keeps saying i need more details so i guess im just gonna talk about some nonsense here.

```
package com.notesquirrel.johnald.memorymagic;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;


public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    View.OnClickListener {

    Animation wobble;


    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String dataName = "MyData";
    String intName = "MyInt";
    int defaultInt = 0;
    int highScore;


    TextView textScore;
    TextView textDifficulty;
    TextView textWatchGo;

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button buttonRestart;


    int difficultyLevel = 3;
    int[] sequenceToCopy = new int[100];

    private Handler myHandler;
    boolean playSequence = false;
    int elementToPlay = 0;

    int playerResponses;
    int playerScore;
    boolean isResponding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        wobble = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wobble);


        prefs = getSharedPreferences(dataName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        highScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);


        final MediaPlayer powerup7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru);
        final MediaPlayer powerup8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru2);
        final MediaPlayer powerup9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru3);
        final MediaPlayer powerup10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru4);

        textScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        assert textScore != null;
        textScore.setText("Score: " + playerScore);

        textDifficulty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDifficulty);
        assert textDifficulty != null;
        textDifficulty.setText("Level: " + difficultyLevel);

        textWatchGo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textWatchGo);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button32);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button43);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button54);
        buttonRestart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRestart);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonRestart.setOnClickListener(this);
        //thread
      myHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                if (playSequence) {

                    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    switch (sequenceToCopy[elementToPlay]) {
                        case 1:
                            // button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            button1.startAnimation(wobble);
                            powerup7.start();
                            break;


                        case 2:
                            //button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            button2.startAnimation(wobble);
                            powerup8.start();
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            //button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            button3.startAnimation(wobble);
                            powerup9.start();
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            // button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            button4.startAnimation(wobble);
                            powerup10.start();
                            break;


                    }
                    elementToPlay++;
                    if (elementToPlay == difficultyLevel) {

                        sequenceFinished();
                    }


                }
                myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 900);
            }
        };
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


        playASequence();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final MediaPlayer powerup7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru);
        final MediaPlayer powerup8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru2);
        final MediaPlayer powerup9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru3);
        final MediaPlayer powerup10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poweru4);


        if (!playSequence) {

            switch (v.getId()) {


                case R.id.button21:
                    powerup7.start();
                    checkElement(1);
                    break;

                case R.id.button32:
                    powerup8.start();
                    checkElement(2);
                    break;

                case R.id.button43:
                    powerup9.start();
                    checkElement(3);
                    break;

                case R.id.button54:
                    powerup10.start();
                    checkElement(4);
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonRestart:
                    difficultyLevel = 3;
                    playerScore = 0;
                    textScore.setText("Score: " + playerScore);
                    playASequence();
                    break;


            }
        }


    }


    public void createSequence() {
        //For choosing a random button
        Random randInt = new Random();
        int ourRandom;
        for (int i = 0; i < difficultyLevel; i++) {
            //get a random number between 1 and 4
            ourRandom = randInt.nextInt(4);
            ourRandom++;//make sure it is not zero
            //Save that number to our array
            sequenceToCopy[i] = ourRandom;
        }

    }


    public void playASequence() {
        createSequence();
        isResponding = false;
        elementToPlay = 0;
        playerResponses = 0;
        textWatchGo.setText("WATCH!");
        playSequence = true;

    }


    public void sequenceFinished() {
        playSequence = false;
        //make sure all the buttons are made visible
        // button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //  button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textWatchGo.setText("GO!");
        isResponding = true;
    }


    public void checkElement(int thisElement) {

        if (isResponding) {
            playerResponses++;
            if (sequenceToCopy[playerResponses - 1] == thisElement) {//Correct
                playerScore = playerScore + ((thisElement + 1) * 2);
                textScore.setText("Score: " + playerScore);
                if (playerResponses == difficultyLevel) {//got the whole     sequence
                    //don't checkElelment anymore
                    isResponding = false;
                    //now raise the difficulty
                    difficultyLevel++;
                    //and play another sequence
                    playASequence();
                }

            } else {//wrong answer

                textWatchGo.setText("FAILED!");
                //don't checkElelment anymore
                isResponding = false;
                if (playerScore > highScore) {
                    highScore = playerScore;
                    editor.putInt(intName, highScore);
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New high score!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }


        }
    }

}
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.notesquirrel.johnald.memorymagic.GameActivity"
android:background="#000000">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Score: 999"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Difficulty: 4"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/textDifficulty"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Watch/Go"
    android:id="@+id/textWatchGo"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDifficulty"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textWatchGo"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textScore" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:layout_below="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button21" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:id="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button32" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:id="@+id/button54"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button43" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Restart"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRestart"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show the layout containing these buttons

Comment: Ok i added it under the java.

Comment: Im new.  Is it possible that not addressing the possible handler leak is causing this?

Comment: Did you test on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Tested on a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem with my device. But I removed some constraints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.notesquirrel.johnald.memorymagic.GameActivity"
  android:background="#000000">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Score: 999"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Difficulty: 4"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/textDifficulty"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Watch/Go"
    android:id="@+id/textWatchGo"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDifficulty"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textWatchGo"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textScore"
 />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button21"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button32"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button54"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button43"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button43"
 />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Restart"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRestart"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok so you figured it out. I had all the views aligning to end of the view above it. So when my java increased the score it increased the width of the first view and that caused the the other views to align to the end of that first view. Then when i lost the game and the score reset it would shrink back down to normal size...

Comment: Did the answer help in solving your problem?